# In-House app disappears from notifications list

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, in-house-distribution

we have developed an in-house iphone app which is downloaded "over the air" (enterprise signed, installing prov. profile before download/install of app).
it installs correctly and our tests show that i receives push notifications (app's main feature).

but strangely, the app sometimes disappears from the notifications list in settings and no more pushes are received. after a reboot of the device the app is back there and remains.

what might be reasons for this behavior? how is an app "removed" from that list?

Comment: it seems to affect iOS 5 only. apple is returning invalid tokens sometimes. is there a bug in APNS?